# How Can I Display SVG Data In React Native?

Tags: react-native, svg

I have some SVG image data that I would like to import into my React Native App.

Is there any way to take my raw SVG image data and display it without saving it to a file?

I have an api that will create an image based from any given text (coolProgrammer123) and will return the SVG image data.

https://api.kwelo.com/v1/media/identicon/coolProgrammer123?format=base64

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you try out [react-native-svg-uri](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri)

```
import SvgUri from 'react-native-svg-uri';

const TestSvgUri = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <SvgUri
      width="200"
      height="200"
      source={{uri:'http://thenewcode.com/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg'}}
    />
  </View>
);
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a code snippet on how you can use to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to get the SVG from the URL and pass it to the `Image` tag without using the above `npm` package.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      imageUri: ''
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSvg();
  }

  getSvg = () => {
    let image_base64;
    axios.get('https://api.kwelo.com/v1/media/identicon/coolProgrammer123?format=base64')
      .then(response => {
        image_base64 = response.data;
        this.setState({
          ...this.state,
          imageUri: image_base64
        })
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
      return image_base64;
  }

render(){
  return (
    <View>
      <Image
        style={{
          width: 81,
          height: 81,
          resizeMode: 'contain',
          marginTop: 180,
          marginLeft: 20,
          marginRight: 20,
          alignSelf: "center"
        }}
        source={{ uri: this.state.imageUri }}
/>
    </View>
  );
}
};



export default App;
```

Comment: this is not what he's asking

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Although, the url is just SVG file data, could I parse it?
https://api.kwelo.com/v1/media/identicon/coolProgrammer44121?format=base64

Comment: Sorry for the late reply [codeshady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9767094/codeshady). I have updated my answer to reflect a direct solution for your use case.
cc: [Cuong Tran Duc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7913142/cuong-tran-duc)